# jquery Datatable pdf & xls report generate not working

Tags: datatables

I am trying to generate xls, csv,pdf report using jquery datatable but its not working.

here is the sample code.
 the css and js links are

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/css/dataTables.tableTools.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.10/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css">
```

here is the onload function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
           $('#example').dataTable({
                    "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
                    "oTableTools": {

                        "sSwfPath": "https://cdn.datatables.net/tabletools/2.2.4/swf/copy_csv_xls_pdf.swf",
                        "aButtons": [
                            {
                                "sExtends":    "collection",
                                "sButtonText":"Save / Print",
                                "sPdfMessage": "My Report",
                                "sTitle": "My Report",
                                "aButtons":    [ "xls", "pdf","print" ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            });
</script>
```

and the table is as follows:

```
<div style="padding:1%">

<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
                <td>System Architect</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>61</td>
                <td>2011/04/25</td>
                <td>$320,800</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>2011/07/25</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>


        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
```

can't understand whats the fault.please help.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the [Buttons](http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/) extension and follow the new documentation, since it changed alot from the previous release.

Here's an example i'm using, with standard buttons

```
dataTable = $('#myTable').DataTable({
                    dom: '<"col-md-7"lr><"col-md-3"B><"col-md-2"f>tr<"col-md-8"i><"col-md-4"p>',
ajax: {
        url: myHandler,
        type: "POST",
    },
    lengthMenu: [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
    buttons: ['copy', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'],
    serverSide: true,
    processing: true,
    autoWidth: true,
    deferRender: true,
});
```

Comment: In the link there are a lot off working examples. See this:
http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/simple.html

Comment: thanks..but am trying this :  http://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/styling/bootstrap.html .but not working properly

Comment: the save files are without any extension